# Chrome cannot play FLV files

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I've been using Google Chrome for a while now.. but for the first time i'm on a dead end: I cannot play a FLV.

It says that the plug-in is not installed, but it doesn't open a bar to download it, and on the "about:plugins" flash is installed.

I'm using Windows 7 by the way, and a page that this occurs for example is: http://noticias.sapo.pt/videos/viagens-e-lifestyle_1291/a86ff84e52bcc82eb7010000/#vervideo

**As you can see:**

[image: Screenshot of Google Chrome]

**Plugins list (from about:plugins) :**

[image]

[image]

Any ideia why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same on the page you linked to and this appears to be a bug with Chrome. But I found a workaround that seems to fix it:

1. Type **chrome://plugins/** into the address bar and hit [enter] (to go to the plugin page in your screenshot)
2. Click the **Details** button in the top right-hand corner.
3. In the Flash section, click the **Disable** link for the one listed in the Users directory, e.g. C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\16.0.912.63\gcswf32.dll
4. Close and reopen Chrome

Based on what was posted [here](http://www.google.co.uk/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=0ff16c45ee447b66&hl=en&start=40)

Answer (score 0):

Adobe acrobat is for viewing pdfs, not flvs. This page http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/839/cpsid_83950.html has information related to Adobe Flash and Chrome. You can also find the link to download the plugin from there if need be.

Comment: Have you seen the 2nd plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I see a problem like this I use the [IE Tab Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) for chrome. It allows you to view that page as a IE while staying in Chrome and generally allows me to see what Chrome would otherwise tell me had a missing plugin such as [Plants vs Zombies](http://chrome.plantsvszombies.com/) doesn't work in Chrome but I pressed the IE Tab plug-in and it works perfectly. It works for [your link](http://noticias.sapo.pt/videos/viagens-e-lifestyle_1291/a86ff84e52bcc82eb7010000/#vervideo) as well.